# How to get current using shards in Elasticsearch or Opensearch

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

My opensearch sometimes reaches this error when i adding new index:

```
Validation Failed: 1: this action would add [2] total shards, but this cluster currently has [1000]/[1000] maximum shards open;
```

So i have to increase *cluster.max_shards_per_node* larger.
I wonder if is there any way to check current shards we are using to avoid this error happening?

Comment: To check on the current shard count, use `GET _cat/allocation?v&s=node` which will return shard and disk allocation of each node in the cluster sorted by node name.

Comment: As I understand, he wants to see which shards (indexes) are actively receiving write and read requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to see **indexing** and **search** activity is by using a monitoring system. And the best monitoring system for Elasticsearch is Opster. You can try it for free at the following link.
https://opster.com/

[image: An example output from AutoOps]

For the manual check and sort, you can try the following APIs.

You can sort your indices according to the `creation date string` (cds). It will help you to understand which one is the old one. So you can have an idea about your indices (shards).

```
GET _cat/indices?v&h=index,cds&s=cds
```

Also, you check the **indices stats** to see if is there any activity in **searching** or **indexing**.

To check all indices you can use `GET _all/_stats`
To check only one index you can use `GET index_name/_stats`
[image]

Comment: Why would you want to list indices based on CSD when you want to check on number of shards in the cluster ?

Comment: Generally in old indices, there were no indexing and search operations. That's why you can check that. And `GET index_name/_stats` command will be more useful to see indexing and search operations.

Comment: http://localhost:9200/_cat/allocation?v&s=node
so when I use this command and sum the total of shards, I will get the number of current shards I am using right?

Comment: That's correct also you can run the following API and see the total shard count `curl localhost:9200/_cat/health?pretty`

Also you can use this one `GET /_cluster/health`

Comment: What are you gonna do when you get the current active shards? Remove the ones which are not in use? Aren't you using some sort of retention based on time etc? You won't have this issue if you use one